# React hook useEffect runs continuously forever/infinite loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying out the new [React Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html)'s `useEffect` API and it seems to keep running forever, in an infinite loop! I only want the callback in `useEffect` to run once. Here's my code for reference:

*Click "Run code snippet" to see the "Run useEffect" string is being printed to the console infinitely.*

```js
function Counter() {
  const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log('Run useEffect');
    setCount(100);
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <p>Count: {count}</p>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<Counter />, document.querySelector('#app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.7.0-alpha.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.7.0-alpha.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 131, accepted):

This happens because `useEffect` is triggered after every render, which is the invocation of the `Counter()` function in this case of functional components. When you do a `setX` call returned from `useState` in a `useEffect`, React will render that component again, and `useEffect` will run again. This causes an infinite loop:

`Counter()` → `useEffect()` → `setCount()` → `Counter()` → `useEffect()` → ... (loop)

To make your `useEffect` run only once, pass an empty array `[]` as the second argument, as seen in the revised snippet below.

The intention of the second argument is to tell React when any of the values in the array argument changes:

```
useEffect(() => {
  setCount(100);
}, [count]); // Only re-run the effect if count changes
```

You could pass in any number of values into the array and `useEffect` will only run when any one of the values change. By passing in an empty array, we're telling React not to track any changes, only run once, effectively simulating `componentDidMount`.

```js
function Counter() {
  const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log('Run useEffect');
    setCount(100);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>Count: {count}</p>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<Counter />, document.querySelector('#app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.7.0-alpha.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.7.0-alpha.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Read up more about [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects).

Comment: This is the solution, however if you are using the `react-hooks` eslint plugin. This would be flagged up by the `exhaustive-deps` rule. It would appear the correct solution is to use the `useCallback` hook, more discussion here: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14920#issuecomment-471070149

Answer (score 3):

You are running into a infinite loop because there is no dependency provided to the written useEffect.

**To avoid an infinite loop when using the useEffect hook, make sure to provide a dependency array that includes all the variables that the effect depends on**

For example, if you only want the **effect to run once when the component mounts**, you can pass an empty dependency array like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
   // effect code here
}, [])
```

If you want the effect to run whenever **a specific variable changes**, you can include that variable in the dependency array:

```
const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

useEffect(() => {
  // effect code here
}, [count])
```