# Why is useEffect() looping endlessly when second argument is being passed in, is there another more effective method?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate, use-effect

Why is `useEffect()` looping endlessly when the second set of arguments is being passed in `[]`? The goal here is to get the state of the last record of `props.state.hours.clockedIn` on-load only (just once), and then store that boolean value to be used elsewhere. If the second argument does not have `props.hours` and `clocked` then `useEffect` does not get the value of the last record and is always `false` (when it should be `true` in this particular case). If they are passed in, I can see in the console.log the `.map` function is working as intended. Does `useEffect()` need to be used here? Is there another method to achieve getting just that last record's `clockedIn` value on-load?

```
const Hours = (props) => {
    const [clocked, setClocked] = useState(false);
    
    useEffect(() => {
        props.fetchHours()
            .then(() => {
                _.map(props.state.hours, (hour) => {
                    setClocked(hour.clockedIn)
                    console.log(clocked)
                })
            })
    }, [props, clocked])

    return (
        <div></div>
    );
};
```

Comment: Because you're modifying `clocked` within `useEffect` thus triggering state update, thus re-render, thus another round of `useEffect`

Comment: @ckingchris You have `clocked` as the dependency in your `useEffect` and inside useEffect you are changing the `clocked` variable which would result in an infinite loop. You should probably remove clocked as the dependency

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React hook useEffect runs continuously forever/infinite loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53243203/react-hook-useeffect-runs-continuously-forever-infinite-loop)

Comment: Try removing `console.log(clocked)` as well as from the dependency array

Answer (score 0):

You use setClocked so you change the value of clocked. Also you have clocked inside the depedency array of useEffect thats why you have an endless loop.

If you want your useEffect to run only the first time that the component is rendered you need an empty depedency array

```
const Hours = (props) => {

const [clocked, setClocked] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
    props.fetchHours()
        .then(() => {
            _.map(props.state.hours, (hour) => {
                setClocked(hour.clockedIn)
                console.log(clocked)
            })
        })
}, [])

return (
    <div></div>
);
```

};

Comment: if the second argument is not passed in, the initial state loads as `false`, when the last record has a state of `true` in this particular case

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use `useEffect()` hook to run some code on load just once after the initial render, the second argument must be an empty array like:

```
useEffect(() => {
  props.fetchHours()
      .then(() => {
          _.map(props.state.hours, (hour) => {
              setClocked(hour.clockedIn)
              console.log(clocked)
          })
      })
}, [])
```

Comment: if the second argument is not passed in, the initial state loads as `false`, when the last record has a state of `true` in this particular case