# How to Stop useEffect running infinitely when using useNavigate inside it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am making an e-store. I have the uid of logged-in user. I am trying to make a condition that if the logged in user uid is not equal to admin uid, then I do not want that user to go on the admin page. The useEffect runs infinite.

```js
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const user = localStorage.getItem("uid");

    useEffect(() => {

        if (user === 'at64ZIYgqaawRyCAkH6xMYBRNwS2') {
            navigate('/admin')
        }
        else {
            navigate('/home')
        }
    })
```

Comment: I believe this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53243203/react-hook-useeffect-runs-continuously-forever-infinite-loop) should answer your question.

Comment: No, it donot answer my question.

Comment: Just add empty dependency array to the useEffect and ignore possible eslint warning.

Comment: With warnings it's re-rendering page inifinitely

Answer (score 0):

To useEffect is't running infinite:

```
useEffect(() => {

//Todo

}, [])
```

You can write variables state in [] or not.

Comment: I have tried dependency array but it does not worked.

Answer (score 0):

You should add dependencies array to the useEffect that means your hook should run every changes of dependencies; So if you wanna run only one time you should add an empty array to useEffect:

```
useEffect(() => {

        if (user === 'at64ZIYgqaawRyCAkH6xMYBRNwS2') {
            navigate('/admin')
        }
        else {
            navigate('/home')
        }
    }, []) // this [] is dependencies array
```

Comment: I have also used dependency array but still giving array. I think the problem is in using useNavigate hook multiple times inside a useEffect

Comment: So change your dependency array to this `[user, navigate]`

Comment: still not working

Answer (score 0):

There are some things I want you to take into considerations.

In order to check if the user is admin or not, do not use this `uid`.

This might work for a single type of applications but suppose there are multiple admins trying to access the application at the same time, it will fail!

To compare the user type, you shouldn't use if else condition with the uid, instead you should fetch a get Api which takes the uid token as query and get the data from the database and then compare the `user_type`.

A basic example would be like this:
**Frontend:**

```
const obj=axios.get("http://localhost:7099")
.then(res=>//..handle response)
.catch(err=>//..handle error)
```

**Backend/Server:**

**USER_OBJECT:**

```
user={
      user_type:"admin" || "default",
      user_name:...,
      user_age:...,
      .
      .
      .
      . 
}
```

And you can use UseEffect like this:

```
useEffect(() => {

//Todo

}, [])
```

Comment: You have given the right suggestion that if I have multiple admins it would be a problem. I will try the approach described by you. But for now, I have tried dependency array as well but it's still running infinitely.

Comment: you can also try using this method, to get rid of your infinite loop, simply use an empty dependency array like so: `const [count, setCount] = useState(0); //only update the value of 'count' when component is first mounted useEffect(() => { setCount((count) => count + 1); }, []);` This will tell React to run `useEffect` on the first render. If still this issue persist, try looking into this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53070970/infinite-loop-in-useeffect)