# react hook causes infinite loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-custom-hooks

I am new in react and I don't know what happens when i try fetch cause infinite loop

```
const useDadosSolicitacao = (idSolicitacao: number) => {
  const [dadosSolicitacaoDevolucaoAmostra, setDadosSolicitacaoDevolucaoAmostra] = useState<IDadosSolicitacaoAmostra>();
  console.log('test');

  const obterDadosSolicitacao = async () => {
    return await DadosSolicitacaoService.obterDadosSolicitacaoDevolucao(1)
      .then((resposta) => {
        setDadosSolicitacaoDevolucaoAmostra(resposta.data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        if (error.response) {
          if (error.response.status === 404) {
            return null;
          }
          return { mensagem: error.response.message };
        }
      });
  };
  obterDadosSolicitacao();
```

this function (obterDadosSolicitacao) generates an infinite loop. But when I don't use response, nothing happens... like it:

```
const obterDadosSolicitacao = async () => {
    return await DadosSolicitacaoService.obterDadosSolicitacaoDevolucao(1);
}
obterDadosSolicitacao()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React hook useEffect runs continuously forever/infinite loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53243203/react-hook-useeffect-runs-continuously-forever-infinite-loop)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const useDadosSolicitacao = (idSolicitacao: number) => {
  const [dadosSolicitacaoDevolucaoAmostra, setDadosSolicitacaoDevolucaoAmostra] = useState<IDadosSolicitacaoAmostra>();
  console.log('test');

  const obterDadosSolicitacao = async () => {
    return await DadosSolicitacaoService.obterDadosSolicitacaoDevolucao(1)
      .then((resposta) => {
        setDadosSolicitacaoDevolucaoAmostra(resposta.data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        if (error.response) {
          if (error.response.status === 404) {
            return null;
          }
          return { mensagem: error.response.message };
        }
      });
  };
  // call it only once
  useEffect(() => {
    obterDadosSolicitacao();
  }, [])
```

Comment: Can you provide some explanation, please?